# Adding IF statements to perform validation from forms

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, function, if-statement

How can I add IF statements displaying alert messages, if the input elements are empty for the following functions in my code `hello()`, `calcAge()` and `add()`.

Apologies if parts of the rest of my code is off or incorrect from the page. All my forms and stuff worked, until I started messing with the IF functions, but I left my work as is for you to see.

```js
function hello() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var yob = document.getElementById("yob").value;
  document.getElementById("pForm").innerHTML = "Hello " + name + " you were born in " + yob;
}

function calcAge() {
  var yob = document.getElementById("yob").value;
  var date = new Date();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var age = year - yob;
  var alreadyOutput = document.getElementById("pForm").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("pForm").innerHTML = alreadyOutput + " you are " + age;
}
var itemArray = [];

function add() {
  var item = document.getElementById('item');
  itemArray.push(item.value);
  item.value = "";
  item.focus();
}

function showList() {
  document.getElementById('pList').innerHTML = itemArray;
}

function clearList() {
  document.getElementById('pList').innerHTML = itemArray = [];
}
if (name = "") {
  alert("Please enter your name and date of birth");
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name;
  hello = false;
}

if (yob = "") {
  alert("Please enter your date of birth");
  document.getElementById("yob").innerHTML = name;
  calcAge = false;
}

if (item = "") {
  alert("Please enter your date of item");
  document.getElementById("item").innerHTML = name;
  add = false;
}
```

```css
form {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border: 1px solid khaki;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

form h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

input {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Practice Manipulating Forms #1</h1>

<form id='calcForm'>
  <h2>Calc Form</h2>
  <span>Name:</span>
  <input type='text' name='name' id='name'><br>
  <span>Year of Birth:</span>
  <input type='text' name='yob' id='yob'><br>

  <input type='button' name='btnCalc' id='btnHello' value='Hello' onclick='hello()'>
  <input type='button' name='btnCalc' id='btnCalc' value='Calc Age' onclick='calcAge()'>

  <p id='pForm'></p>
</form>

<form id='listForm'>
  <h2>List Form</h2>

  <span>Item:</span>
  <input type='text' name='item' id='item'><br>

  <input type='button' name='btnAdd' id='btnAdd' value='Add to List' onclick='add()'>
  <input type='button' name='btnClear' id='btnClear' value='Clear List' onclick='clearList()'>
  <input type='button' name='btnShow' id='btnShow' value='Show List' onclick='showList()'>

  <p id='pList'></p>
</form>
```

Comment: You are learning javascript ... thats much better than Java :)

Comment: use `==` to compare variables inside your `if` statements like `if (name == "") {`

Comment: *Hi I'm very new to Java so please go easy on me* This question is not tagged Java, but Javascript.

Comment: With `=` you assign a new value to something. So `item = ""` sets `item` to an empty string. You instead want to compare `item === ""`. As `""` is falsy, you can simplify the check to `if(!item)` where `!` means *not*

Comment: Those `if` statements belong inside of their respective functions. Currently, they're in global scope which means they only run once when the page first loads.

Comment: Thank you it seems I have gotten it to work by putting the statements inside their respective functions & following everyone's suggestions. I also messed up some of it, by not closing some of the functions. Only problem I'm having now is having to refresh the web page after checking if the alerts work to be able to input name, year of birth, etc again. At least its a step forward.